# Using Jenkins Version Environment Variable in the MSBuild step

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm currently using the Jenkins "Version Number Plug-In" to set an Environment Variable for build version. This works fine within jenkins but i need a way to pass this to MSBuild so the Version Number of the exe's and dll's are updated. I tried the config bellow but it does not update the builds version

[image: Version Number Config]

[image: Build Config]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Environment Variable Name** should be written *without* the percent-marks ('%'), like this:

```
VERSION
```

apart from that, I think you are good to go.

May also consider changing
`${BUILDS_ALL_TIME}`
 to
`${BUILDS_ALL_TIME, XX}`

(this will enforce a two-digit build-number with leading zeros)

Comment: Yeah i figured that out, Also it seems like MSBuild.exe dosn't support /p:version by default. you need to mess around with MSBuld Extensions. I ended up just writing a console app to update the AssemblyInfo.cs before building and call it passing in the environment variable. This was quicker than messing around with complicated msbuild extensions

Comment: Well, I was hoping you DID find a nice way to pass the version to the build, as we also use a tailored script for that...

Answer (score 2):

This is a MSBuild target that replaces the revision number in the file GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs with the SVN_REVISION variable from Jenkins.

We have a multi project solution where each project references the same GlobalAssemblyInfo for common information (like version). Modify this so it fits your setup.

By having the Exists condition the target executes on developer machines where the MSBuildCommunityTasks is not installed.
In those cases the version number in GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs is left untouched.

```
<Target Name="InjectSVNRevision" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets')">
<!-- When this build is done by the Jenkins CI server; the svn revision number is set in the environment variable SVN_REVISION
     This little snippet replaces the revision number in GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs with this svn revision number
  -->
<Message Text="Injecting SVN revision number in GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" />
<FileUpdate Files="GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs"
    Multiline="true"
    Singleline="false"
    Regex="(AssemblyVersion|AssemblyFileVersionAttribute|AssemblyFileVersion)\(&quot;([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?&quot;\)"
    ReplacementText="$1(&quot;$2.$(SVN_REVISION)&quot;)" 
    Condition="$(SVN_REVISION) != '' "/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I´ve found to do this is using the [Change Assembly Version](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+Assembly+Version). Using that plugin you only need to provide the version number (or the environment variable used) and it will replace it in all the AssemblyInfo.cs files in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick work around to this is to create a powershell task before your msbuild task. This is assuming you defined VERSION variable as above (without the %%). And you checked delete workspace before build starts.

This is the code for the powershell task.

```
gci -rec -Filter *AssemblyInfo* | ForEach { (Get-Content $_.FullName) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "1.0.0.0",$env:VERSION } | Set-Content $_.FullName}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my summary what was necessary to make it work:

Install this Plugins:

```
https://plugins.jenkins.io/versionnumber/
https://plugins.jenkins.io/change-assembly-version-plugin/
```

make sure your AssemblyInfo.cs contains:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Set your version variable name without '$'.

Define a nice version number like: '1.1.${BUILD_NUMBER}.${SVN_REVISION}'

[image]

Add the 'Change Assembly Version'-Build Step.
Enter your variable inside '${...}' example: '${VERSION}'
[image]

If you still get build error. Check you project file and AssemblyInfo.cs for merge conflicts.