# How to setup MSBuild extensions to use Jenkins Version Environment Variable in the MSBuild step?

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am refering to below question on the stackoverflow.

[Using Jenkins Version Environment Variable in the MSBuild step.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345356/using-jenkins-version-environment-variable-in-the-msbuild-step)

Answer (score 0):

If jenkins creates  an environmental variable called version then you can to refer to it in msbuild using $(VERSION).